# Handle no internet connection axios, react native app (without NetInfo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen where image from API rerender every N second. And I would like to handle situation when user didn't connected to the Internet. I was trying to solve this through state, but it's not working. How can i solve this problem?

```
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();
const [err, setErr] = useState(false);

const getImage = () =>
        Axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    setErr(true);
                }
            })
            .then(data => setImgUrl(data.message))
            .catch(err=>console.warn(err));

useEffect(() => {
 getImage();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(getImage, value * 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, [value]);

return (
  <View>
    {err === false ? <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri: `${imgUrl}` }} /> : <View><Text> please, check your network connection! </Text></View>}                                                   
  </View>
  <Text>{value}</Text>
  <Slider value={value} onValueChange={(sliderValue) => setValue(sliderValue)} />

);
```

Comment: Hello, can you be more explicit ? What is not working ?

Comment: what kind of handler you wanted to implement when the app is not connected to the internet?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé . Instead of  ''please, check your network connection!''  empty space (no image, no text) or when user is not connected to the internet. Or image came 1 time from API and then noting happens

Comment: @novalagung . I just want text "please, check your network connection" instead of image which didn't  come

Answer (score 0):

in your catch block of the Axois.post, also call setErr(true);

```
 Axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    setErr(true);
                }
            })
            .then(data => setImgUrl(data.message))
            .catch(err=>setErr(true)) // Changed;
```

because if there is no internet axois will throw an error and the catch block will be invoked insted of the then block

Answer (score 0):

The first promise handler of your axios code is not returning a valid promise object, that's why the 2nd promise handler is never called.

Try to put the `setImgUrl()` statement inside the the first promise handler when response status is ok.
And also when some error is occurred, do put the `setErr(true)` as well in the catch handler.

```js
Axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            setImgUrl(response.data.message);
        } else {
            setErr(true);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setErr(true);
        console.warn(err)
    });
```

Or, wrap the returned `response.data` variable inside `Promise.resolve()`.

```js
Axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return Promise.resolve(response.data);
        } else {
            setErr(true);
        }
    })
    .then(data => setImgUrl(data.message))
    .catch(err => {
        setErr(true);
        console.warn(err)
    });
```